# Why does the Google Photo App (not storage of photos) take up 0.92 GB? Samsung S 7

Tags: photos, google-photos

I've 'freed up space' so that the actual photo storage should be entirely empty, yet my phone shows 0.92 gb of storage taken up. As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with the images on my phone; I've checked in all the other folders and there's nothing that would indicate why this amount of space would be taken up by the app itself.

I've tried googling the problem, but all of the answers point to stories about how Photos stores your photos in the cloud, how that policy is changing, how to 'free up space' by uploading, etc.

I've done all that! And the app is still too huge.

Maybe it's got it's own hidden cache or something that I can clear? (I've already cleared the cache via the app management tools in settings.)

Comment: this app has trash bin containing deleted pictures in app data directory

Comment: This was it! Thank you! I hope someone else finds this post when they have the same problem!

(I had accidentally created a video from my camera that ate up a bunch of MB, it was sitting in my trash bin but still taking up app storage space.)

Answer (score 2):

User @alecks answered this for me: the 'trash' folder in Google Photos was the culprit of taking up space.

I had one video file in there from my phone accidentally captured 3 minutes of video in my pocket, taking up hundreds of MB. I deleted it (and a bunch of other photos) and now the app is taking up 400+ MB instead of 0.97 GB.

TL;DR - if your Google Photos seems to take up too much space and you've already uploaded all of your photos off your phone, the trash bin may be holding a lot of files or a few big ones. They clear after 60 days, for what that's worth!